# Validate that a PHP file only contains array inside

Tags: php, arrays, regex, validation, security

I have a configuration .php file that contains an array ( it **has** to be a PHP Array ) that contains something similar to:

```
<?php
return array(
  'api_key'     => 'e3awY0HoZr0c6L0791Wl2dA3',
  'user'     => 'Lequis',
  'timeout'     => '4'
);
```

These files are uploaded by users, i'd like to validate that the user doesn't add any malicious code, since these files will only contain an array, i'd like to validate that it is in fact only an array

Comment: Why use an array. Have them send JSON instead.

Comment: @JayBlanchard is right. JSON will be better fit, especially because nothing prevents from adding closure as a value in array so it is not secure at in scenario when user uploads this file.

Comment: You can technically do something like - `$array = include __DIR__ . '/path/to/array.php'; $isArray = is_array($array);` - if the returned content from the other file is an array it'll resolve as `true`. However this really doesn't do anything to check for malicious code and I don't see how you could reliably mitigate for that, so I concur with @JayBlanchard and @Adam

Comment: Dito @JayBlanchard JSON is awesome.

Comment: Regarding the "it has to be a PHP Array" remark: `json_decode($jsondata, true);` - now it's a php array (or, yes, a scalar, but that would probably just handled as an input format error).

Comment: Even if it is just an array, there could still be malicious PHP code inside one of the elements, so there's no way to be safe unless you have some kind of sandbox to evaluate it in.

Comment: @JayBlanchard i agree that JSON might be better, but i'm using Laravel framework which uses arrays in their configuration files which i will be utilizing

Comment: @jgivoni that's actually a good point too, but since i'm using laravel framework i'm stuck with arrays

Comment: You could still have the user submit JSON which then *you* process into an array. It would be much safer.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** see @VolkerK's comment regarding how this doesn't guard against the injection of malicious code.

Like @Jay Blanchard said, it may be better to actually think of a more appropriate data structure such as JSON. If you do want to stick to this structure however, you can use PHP's is_array() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) function to validate that a variable is an array before trying to pass that array to any other functions.

That only validates that you do have an array, and not that your array is in the proper format. To go one step further, you can validate that the array is of the right size using the count() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function, these two things combined will ensure that you have an array with the correct number of values stored in the array.

The problem of checking to see whether or not the array values are in the correct format is a different beast. You can run through all of the keys and compare the passed key to an array of acceptable keys like so:

```
function isValidArr($usrArr){

$apiParams = array('api_key', 'user', 'timeout');

for($i = 0; i < count($usrArr); $i++ {
   if(!strcmp($usrArr[$i], $apiParams[$i])) {
    return false;
   }
  }
}
```

And then to check the values associated with each of the keys, I assume that the api_key is of a specific length or within a range, so you could check against that. For the timeout, you could ensure that the value is an integer. To validate against the username, you could implement a regex to ensure that the value adheres to a specific format.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but after the first sentence the answer misses the real point: checking the code _before_ it gets executed (by being included), e.g. `<?php return array('foo'=>exec('rm -r /*')); `

Comment: That makes complete sense! Thanks for the feedback. I'm going to leave my answer up for the sake of keeping your comment up here.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what you want to check, an array or values?

If array, then, i think you can use simply `is_array($arr)` func.

If values, then there is a good Symfony component [SymfonyOptionsResolver](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html)

You can use it like a validator for value types/values etc.

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    // ...
    $resolver->setAllowedTypes('host', 'string');
    $resolver->setAllowedTypes('port', array('null', 'int'));
}
```

Or use some normalizer and check value with `preg_match`:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    // ...

    $resolver->setNormalizer('host', function (Options $options, $value) {
        if ('http://' !== substr($value, 0, 7)) {
            $value = 'http://'.$value;
        }

        return $value;
    });
}
```

Check [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html) for additional info.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What if the OP is not using Symfony?

Comment: It can be used like a standalone package, it's not require symfony.